# Get highest & lowest data based on a whereHas query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.3

Based on an `apartment finder` all `types` which has `apartments`, based on the form search are being shown/returned. This is being done using a `whereHas` query.

So for example:

> A user has different choices; a garden/balcony, price range, floor
>   etc.
>
> The query is being run based on these choices, and if there are
>   apartments which meet the search requirements the **parent** of these
>   apartments (**type**) are being returned.

Ultimately I want to display the `living surface` range `(lowest-highest)` of a type, but the `living surface` is different for each `apartment`.

What would be the most effective way to get the `highest` **and** `lowest` `apartment.living_surface` being returned by the `whereHas`.

```
$types = Type::where('type', '=', 'studio')->whereHas('apartments', function ($query) use ($request) {
    if ($request->view == 'garden') {
        $query->where('view', '=', $request->view);
    } elseif ($request->view == 'balcony') {
        $query->where('view', '=', $request->view);
    } elseif ($request->view == 'other') {
        $query->where('view', '=', $request->view);
    }

    if ($request->floor == 'upper') {
        $query->where('floor', '<', '5');
    } elseif ($request->floor == 'lower') {
        $query->where('floor', '>', '4');
    }

    if ($request->sun == 'morning') {
        $query->where('sun', '=', 'morning');
    } elseif ($request->sun == 'evening') {
        $query->where('sun', '=', 'evening');
    }

    if ($request->price == '1') {
        $query->where('price', '<', '900');
    } elseif ($request->price == '2') {
        $query->where('price', '<', '999');
    } elseif ($request->price == '3') {
        $query->where('price', '>', '999');
    }
})->with('apartments')->get();
```

One solution would be (I think) is to pluck all `ids` of the `apartments` and run another query based on the `ids`, but this wouldn't really be as optimized as possible due to running multiple queries for something (I hope) to be done within one query.

Comment: What's the point of the first three wheres? The end result, regarding the choice is adding the value of whatever is contained in `request->view` to the where clause. My PHP is a bit rusty, and I might be missing something, but it seems to lead to the exact same result, regardless of what the user selected.

Comment: To answer your question, though, you probably want to use a MIN and MAX statement to grab the living_surface, and use GROUP BY on the type. However, without knowing your data model, it's hard to say exactly what to do.

Comment: @SchmitzIT good notice, I could change the first three and just check if the data is set and then run the query with the $request->view, and for the latter comment; can this be done within the same query?

Comment: It all depends on what your query currently looks like. All we see here is some PHP code, but nothing related to the query it is building. It should be possible, but it depends on whatever is already in there and that could possibly affect the rest of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by the `Collection Methods` - [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections)

It is possible to run methods over the queried collection - in this case `$types`

```
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $type->lowest_living_area = $type->apartments>sortBy('living_area')->first()->living_area);
    $type->highest_living_area = $type->apartments->sortBy('living_area')->last()->living_area);
}
```